# mongodb: number of collections in database - native driver

Tags: mongodb, node-mongodb-native

I'm using the mongodb native driver v3.2.3 and trying to query how many collections are in the current database. I thought it would be

```
db.listCollections()
```

But this does not appear to return a count.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the collection count of a database via the [`stats`](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.0/api/Db.html#stats) method:

```
let stats = await db.stats();
console.log(stats.collections);
```

Answer (score 0):

That function returns a cursor which you can then use 'forEach()' on. Like this:

```
db.listCollections({}, {nameOnly: true}).forEach((_col) => {
  console.log(_col.name)
})
```

You will then have to increment a counter for each collection, or push each collection name to an array and then check it's length.

---

Another way to get the collection count quickly would be to use the 'collections()' function like this:

```
db.collections({}, (error, collections) => {
  console.log(collections.length)
})
```

[listCollections source](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html#listCollections)
[collections source](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.1/api/Db.html#collections)